# How to include JSTL / EL footers inside a .jsp?

Tags: java, import, include, jstl, el

I've got a simple .jsp file using *<c:import url="...jsp">* for header and footer.

For the header it works great: there's some ${...} EL substitution being done inside the *header.jsp* that I *c:import* and every time the user reloads the page everything is fine and well.

However in the footer there's something I don't get: I tried to put some JSTL inside my *footer.jsp* but it doesn't work.

Instead of evaluating the JSTL the tags in my footer.jsp are served to the browser.

For example, if I ask to view the page source code from Chrome I see:

```
<div>
    <c:if test="false">
       ...
    </c:if>
</div>
```

The header.jsp and footer.jsp are both imported using *c:import*.  How comes EL substitution works but JSTL tags do not?

If I need to "include" instead of "import", then I've got two questions:

- can I "include" using JSTL and if so how?
- how comes EL substitution is still taking place when I do a *c:import* while JSTL tag do not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed use `<%@ include file="footer.jsp" %>` - then all EL will be resolved (same goes for header)

`<c:import />` evaluates the target resource and then includes it in the page. If your footer does not declare EL expression parsing properly (in older versions of JSP it is not on by default), then the included result would contain `<c:` tags.

Comment: I did try and using that include directive (?) does indeed work.  However could you clarify a bit what you mean by *"If your footer does not declare EL expression parsing properly, then included result would contain <c: tags"* ?   Now this may be the subject of another question but: when am I supposed to use the *%@include* construct and when am I supposed to use *c:import*.  Or: what does c:import do that *%@include* doesn't!?  I think I'm seriously confused on this...

Comment: c:import imports any resource, not only a jsp. You can even import an external page. And it does that dynamically. %@include includes the content statically before the jsp is compiled, so ontop of everything - it is more performant